# Help confirming my proof and the answer key of $(\exists!x)P(x)$ as equivelant to the following?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In a transition to advanced mathematics, fourth edition, chapter 1.3 #11. It want to prove

> 1. $(\exists!x)P(x)$ is equivelant to $(\exists x)A(x) \land (\forall y)(\forall z)\left[A(y)\land A(z)\!\!\implies \!\! y=z\right]$
> 2. $(\exists!x)P(x)$ is equivelant to $(\exists x)\left[A(x)\!\!\implies \!\! x=y\right]$

### Attempt at Solving Problem #1

$(\exists!x)P(x)$ is true in Universe U

iff There exists a unique x where P(x) is true in Universe U

iff There exists some x where A(x) is true and two elements of property A are the same element

iff $(\exists x)A(x) \land (\forall y)(\forall z)\left[A(y)\land A(z)\!\!\implies \!\! y=z\right]$

### Answer Key To Problem #1

I couldn't fully undestand the answer key

> 1. $(\exists !)A(x)$ is true in Universe U
> 2. Then $(\exists ! x) A(x)$ implies that A(x) is true for unique x in U
> 3. iff $(\exists ! x) A(x)$ is not true for every x in U
> 4. iff there exists some $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $(\exists x)A(x) \land (\forall y)(\forall z)\left[A(y)\land A(z)\right]$ for $y=z$
> 5. iff $(\exists ! x) A(x)$ is equivelant to $(\exists!x)P(x)$ is equivelant to $(\exists x)A(x) \land (\forall y)(\forall z)\left[A(y)\land A(z)\!\!\implies \!\! y=z\right]$

### Questions

In the answer key I don't understand step 4. Shouldn't some $y$ and $z$ give $(\exists x)A(x) \land (\exists y)(\exists z)\left[A(y)\land A(z)\right]$ for $y=z$? Is my answer correct?

Since this post is long I will save the second part of #11 for another post.

Comment: You have to use either P or A in both formulas.

Comment: See [Uniqueness quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification#Reduction_to_ordinary_existential_and_universal_quantification)

Comment: 2. is wrongly written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the answer key I don't understand step 4. Shouldn't some y and z give (∃x)A(x)∧(∃y)(∃z)[A(y)∧A(z)] for y=z?

For sure, that answer key *is* rather misleading.

You do *not* want to say that there exists *some* $y$ and $z$ where if each satisfies $A$ then they are then same. The claim needs to be that when *any* $y$ and $z$ both satisfy $A$ then they must be the same.

$$\Big(\forall y~\forall z~\big((A(y)\land A(z))\to (y=z)\big)\Big)$$

Alternatively, we could say that when two variables are distinct, then at least one will not satisfy $A$: $$\Big(\forall y~\forall z~\big((y\neq z)\to(\lnot A(y)\lor\lnot A(z))\big)\Big)$$

---

> Is my answer correct?

Yes, you have got it.

The *full claim* of uniqueness is that there is something that satisfies $A$ **and** when *any* $y$ and $z$ both satisfy $A$ then they must be the same.

$$\Big(\exists x~A(x)\Big)~\land~\Big(\forall y~\forall z~\big((A(y)\land A(z))\to (y=z)\big)\Big)$$

---

Of course, you may compact this to claim: There is something which satisfies $A$ and anything which satisfies $A$ is that thing.  $$\exists x~\big(A(x)\land\forall y~(A(y)\to x=y)\big)$$

Or "There is something which satisfies $A$, and anything *else* does not."$$\exists x~\big(A(x)\land\forall y~(x\neq y\to\lnot A(y)\big)$$